# An efficient way to record time taken to execute a method in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I'm looking for a simple, reusable way to record the time taken to execute a method in my .NET (MVC) project and record it it using [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/) and wondered if anybody had any suggestions on how to implement this?

To maintain clean code and readability, I don't really want to have to integrate it into my code if possible.

If anybody has any suggestions, I'd love to hear them.

Comment: Not necessarily for logging ... but the EQATEC Profiler is nicer for, well, profiling. I'm sure other similar tools exists. It works by rewriting the assembly for the method entry/exits for timing information. Not the least intrusive...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to have a look at this:

http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/

Written by the good people at stack exchange.

Comment: as a caveat: to time a method you would ned to add a tiny bit of code. It *could* be done via AOP, but we're of the view that : performance is a feature; it is OK to write code to support features

Answer (score 10):

Use [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class

```
Stopwatch time = Stopwatch.StartNew();
time.Stop();
var milliseconds= time.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I currently do. I'm looking for a way to implement this without writing any code in the method.

Answer (score 5):

Since you mention you would like to avoid changing existing code, this is a case where AOP (aspect oriented programming) comes in handy

Here's a blog post that describes exactly this scenario using PostSharp: 
http://theburningmonk.com/2010/03/aop-method-execution-time-watcher-with-postsharp/

Comment: in our case, we also publish these timespan metrics to Amazon CloudWatch so that we have a psudo real-time view of what's going on and can set up alarms around those metrics too so that we get notified if say, latency problems are occuring and react quickly (http://theburningmonk.com/2012/03/recording-for-my-webinar-with-postsharp/)